# Why are these ulong arrays not considered equal?

Tags: c#, arrays, mstest

Consider the function:

```
public static ulong[] productFib(ulong prod)
    {
        ulong fib1 = 0;
        ulong fib2 = 1;

        while ((fib1 * fib2) < prod)
        {
            ulong temp = fib1;
            fib1 = fib2;
            fib2 = temp + fib2;

        }

        return new ulong[] { fib1, fib2, 1 };
    }
```

I am working through a kata whose test looks like the following:

```
ulong[] r = new ulong[] { 55, 89, 1 };
Assert.AreEqual(r, Kata.productFib(4895));
```

In the immediate window, I can see that the return array is not only of type `ulong` but has the 3 elements I expect, yet MSTest fails with:

`Message: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<System.UInt64[]>. Actual:<System.UInt64[]>.`

Is there something wrong with the test assertion, or my function, that would cause this test to fail?

Thank you

Comment: arrays are reference types, so you're not checking if they contain the same values, but if they are the exact same reference.  Use `CollectionAssert.AreEqual` instead.

Comment: @juharr wish I could - the test is controlled by the application presenting the kata. Interestingly, I just discovered the same code passes the test presented by the kata.

Comment: If you cannot use `CollecitonAssert` then just write a `for` loop and compare the values in the arrays to each other.

Comment: Another option would be to switch to `Tuple<ulong, ulong, ulong>` since you only seem to deal with 3 values and since `Tuple` overrides `Equals` so `Assert.AreEqual` would do what you expect.

Comment: Thanks. What I find curious is the tests associated with the kata pass "as is", using the application's UI, and NUnit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Assert.AreEqual()` uses the `Equals()` method of the passed arguments. And arrays simply compare their references, not their content. So two different array *instances* will never pass this test.

You may use linq [`SequenceEqual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal) like that:

```
Assert.IsTrue(r.SequenceEqual(Kata.productFib(4895)));
```

Answer (score 1):

C# arrays are reference types. `Assert.AreEqual()` will checking for reference equality rather than if you'd passed value types.